# Computer power source

Tags: power-supply, computers

I have a computer that stopped working and I think the problem is the power source but I'm not sure.

I have other power source from another computer that I would like to use to test but first I would like to be sure if there is no harm to use it, if it is compatible.

The power source that I think is not working has these specs

> INPUT
>   100V-127V/6A 60Hz
>   200V-240V/3A 50Hz
>   ------OUTPUT
>   +3.3V+5V+12V-12V-5V+5V Sb
>   ------MAX(A)
>   14A 22A 8A 0.8A 0.5A 0.1A
>   +5V  &+3.3V   MAX-120W

The power source that I could use to test has these specs

> INPUT(50Hz-60Hz)
>   100V-127V~/6A
>   200V-240V~/3A
>   -----OUTPUT
>   +5V/22A
>   +3.3V/18A
>   +5Vfp/2A
>   +12V/14A
>   -12V/1A
>   +5V AND +3.3V SHALL NOT EXCEED 150W
>   -----MAX OUTPUT POWER: 250W

Any harm on trying that power source to test?

And just another question. What are the specs of the fuse these power supplies has inside? Are they standard?

Comment: I don't think they generally have a real fuse inside, but if there is one the specs are usually printed on one of the metal parts at the ends.

Answer (score 2):

Check,for each voltage, that the replacement can deliver at least the current that the coriginal can deliver. That seems to be the case. If the connectors are the same, I see no harm in trying (unless of course the replacement is bad).

The specs of a fuse are hwat the designer intended them to be. In most cases it will be mentioned somewhere on the case or the PCB.

Answer (score 1):

ASsuming same connectors, looks like your replacement exceeds the original in every voltage and total power rating of 250W vs 120W.  Keep in mind most switchers need at least 10% rated power to be applied on main supply (3.3V) to achieve good regulation, sometimes get high Vdc otherwise. Easy to check. SHould be ok.